# How to call node.js file from Android to retrieve images in Viewpager

Tags: android, mysql, node.js

I am creating Slider in android application, for that I have used Viewpager control.
I have stored all the required images in Slider table of my database.

I have created REST API using Node.js to retrieve data in JSON format.

But actually I do not know how to call Node.js RESTAPI in android to retrive Images in viewpager.

```
Server.js File

/*SERVER.JS FILE FOR NODE.JS CODING */

var app   = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'lut',
  });
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Use to retrive data in JSON format


app.get('/',function(req,res){
  var data = {
    "Data":""
  };
  data["Data"] = "Welcome to LetUsTEll DEMO...";
  res.json(data);
});


//GET images of the slider from database.
app.get('/sliders',function(req,res){
  var data = {
    "error":1,
    "SliderImages":""
  };

  connection.query("SELECT * from slider",function(err, rows, fields){
    if(rows.length != 0){
      data["error"] = 0;
      data["SliderImages"] = rows;
      res.json(data);
    }else{
      data["SliderImages"] = 'No Slider Image Found..';
      res.json(data);
    }
  });
});
http.listen(8080,function(){
  console.log("Connected & Listen to port 8080");
});
```

Android Code :

```
    private ViewPager intro_images;
    private CustomSwipeAdapter mAdapter;
    private Handler handler;
    private ViewPager intro_images;
    private LinearLayout pager_indicator;
    private int dotsCount;
    private ImageView[] dots;
    JSONArray dataCategory;
     public CategoryFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        handler = new Handler();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
        ActionBar bar = CommonUtil.getActionBar(getActivity());
        bar.setTitle("Ask in Bhuj");

        FrameLayout fm = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fl_category);
       /* int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) fm.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = (int) (height / 4);
        fm.setLayoutParams(params);*/
        scrollView = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

        new_features = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newfeaturesView);

        // ViewPager Adapter to set image
        intro_images = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        intro_images.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.d("page changed", String.valueOf(position));
                /*try {
//                    JSONArray productArray = new JSONArray(SharedPreferenceUtil.getString(Constants.PrefKeys.PREF_PROD_LIST, ""));
                   // ProductGridAdapter.getLastItem();
                  //  Glide.with(CategoryFragment.this).load(Constants.BASE_IMAGE_URL + dataCategory.getJSONObject(position).getString("image_name")).centerCrop().into(imageView);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

//  mAdapter = new NewFeatureAdapter(getActivity(), imgresource);
        mAdapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(getActivity(), imgresource);
        pager_indicator = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);

        intro_images.setAdapter(mAdapter);
         intro_images.setCurrentItem(0);
        intro_images.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

        setUiPageViewController();
        //For Automatic Slider after 5secs used Handler
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (position >= imgresource.length) {
                    position = 0;
                } else {
                    position = position + 1;
                }
                // Setting current Image into viewpager
                intro_images.setCurrentItem(position, true);
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);


            }
        };
        //category details in grid view
        mGridCategory = (ExpandableHeightGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_category);
        mGridCategory.setExpanded(true);
/*
        mGridCategory.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                int action = event.getActionMasked();

                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
*/
       // mGridCategory.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
       // ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity());
        mGridCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mGridCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        return rootView;


    }
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can guide me ?